# environment-modules package breaks flashback

Tags: apt, gnome-flashback

After installing the `environment-modules` packages (with `apt`, if it matters) the `flashback` Gnome graphical session fails to load correctly (on Ubuntu 18.04, at least). I would appreciate any help in debugging this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After installing `environment-modules` package with `apt` the following dialog usually appears when starting a graphical session:

[image: Modules installation issue on Ubuntu 18.04]

This is due to a bad dependency definition in `environment-modules` ubuntu package, which depends on `tcl` package whereas only `tcl86` is automatically installed by `apt`.

To solve this issue, install manually the `tcl` package:

```
$ apt-get install tcl
```

This issue has been solved on `environment-modules` ubuntu packaging in [newer versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modules/4.3.0-2) available starting Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for developing `environment-modules`. Unfortunately, what you suggest doesn't solve the problem for me. `apt` is also telling me that `tcl is already the newest version (8.6.0+9)`. Besides that, I do not get the error you report.

Comment: @Miguel: Could you please provide details of the error you get, what error message is printed or recorded in logs

Comment: I don't get any error message printed on the screen. Which log files should I be looking for? /usr/bin/tclsh exists.

Comment: I ended up installing from source. To me, this looks like it could be a problem loading the profile, since I have `tclsh`. By the way, in the error message you posted you had `sh` as default shell, while I have `bash`. I changed the default shell `chsh -s sh` and rebooted to try and reproduce the error message, but I still got nothing (and the same broken behavior for the `flashback` graphical session).

Answer (score 0):

Initialization error failing the X session manager to start correctly should be seen in the X session manager logs.

The following commands run from a terminal session will display the logs of the GDM session manager from the last hour:

```
journalctl --since=-1h _COMM=gdm-x-session
```

Shell profile initialization occurs at the end of X session initialization, so errors occurring there should be spotted in last part of the logs.